# Null pointer on 2nd loop through XML?

Tags: java, xml

I'm new to Java / XML and I'm trying to parse an XML document. I can navigate through the nodes and get the elements for the first node I'm interested in but as soon as I try to go through the second node I'm getting a null pointer exception.

Here is a sample of the XML..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ICD10CM.index>
  <version>2019</version>
  <title>ICD-10-CM INDEX TO DISEASES and INJURIES</title>
  <letter>
    <title>A</title>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Aarskog's syndrome</title>
      <code>Q87.1</code>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Abandonment</title>
      <see>Maltreatment</see>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Abasia<nemod>(-astasia) (hysterical)</nemod></title>
      <code>F44.4</code>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Abderhalden-Kaufmann-Lignac syndrome<nemod>(cystinosis)</nemod></title>
      <code>E72.04</code>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Abdomen, abdominal</title>
      <seeAlso>condition</seeAlso>
      <term level="1">
        <title>acute</title>
        <code>R10.0</code>
      </term>
      <term level="1">
        <title>angina</title>
        <code>K55.1</code>
      </term>
      <term level="1">
        <title>muscle deficiency syndrome</title>
        <code>Q79.4</code>
      </term>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Abdominalgia</title>
      <see>Pain, abdominal</see>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Abduction contracture, hip or other joint</title>
      <see>Contraction, joint</see>
    </mainTerm>
<mainTerm>
      <title>Azygos</title>
      <term level="1">
        <title>continuation inferior vena cava</title>
        <code>Q26.8</code>
      </term>
      <term level="1">
        <title>lobe<nemod>(lung)</nemod></title>
        <code>Q33.1</code>
      </term>
    </mainTerm>
  </letter>
  <letter>
    <title>B</title>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Baastrup's disease</title>
      <see>Kissing spine</see>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Babesiosis</title>
      <code>B60.0</code>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Babington's disease<nemod>(familial hemorrhagic telangiectasia)</nemod></title>
      <code>I78.0</code>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Babinski's syndrome</title>
      <code>A52.79</code>
    </mainTerm>
</letter>
  <letter>
    <title>Z</title>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Zahorsky's syndrome<nemod>(herpangina)</nemod></title>
      <code>B08.5</code>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Zellweger's syndrome</title>
      <code>Q87.89</code>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Zenker's diverticulum<nemod>(esophagus)</nemod></title>
      <code>K22.5</code>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Ziehen-Oppenheim disease</title>
      <code>G24.1</code>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Zieve's syndrome</title>
      <code>K70.0</code>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Zika NOS</title>
      <code>A92.5</code>
      <term level="1">
        <title>congenital</title>
        <code>P35.4</code>
      </term>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Zinc</title>
      <term level="1">
        <title>deficiency, dietary</title>
        <code>E60</code>
      </term>
      <term level="1">
        <title>metabolism disorder</title>
        <code>E83.2</code>
      </term>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Zollinger-Ellison syndrome</title>
      <code>E16.4</code>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Zona</title>
      <see>Herpes, zoster</see>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Zoophobia</title>
      <code>F40.218</code>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Zoster<nemod>(herpes)</nemod></title>
      <see>Herpes, zoster</see>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Zygomycosis</title>
      <code>B46.9</code>
      <term level="1">
        <title>specified NEC</title>
        <code>B46.8</code>
      </term>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>Zymotic</title>
      <see>condition</see>
    </mainTerm>
  </letter>
</ICD10CM.index>
```

And then my Code:

```
 try {
    // Create Results File
    File file = new File("ICD10-Parsed.txt");
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);    

    //Build XML Document and get from url
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse("h:/Application/API/icd10trial.xml");
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("letter");

    System.out.println("----------------------------");

    System.out.println("Number of nodes " + nList.getLength());
    //Testing Area

    for (int i =0; i<1 /*nList.getLength()*/;){
        Node cNode = nList.item(i);
        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element: " + cNode.getNodeName());

        if (cNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element eElement = (Element) cNode;
            System.out.println("Letter: " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("mainTerm").item(i).getTextContent());

            NodeList lList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("mainTerm");
             for (int x =0; x<lList.getLength();){
                 Node tNode = lList.item(x);

                if (cNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    String condition ="";
                    Element tElement = (Element) tNode;
                    NodeList tList = tElement.getElementsByTagName("title");

                    //Get Condition
                    NodeList elements = tElement.getElementsByTagName("title");
                    Node item = elements.item(i);
                    condition = item.getTextContent();
                    //condition = tElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(i).getTextContent();
                    System.out.println("Condition: " + condition);
                    fileWriter.write(condition +";");     
                }
               x++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        i++;
    }


    fileWriter.flush();
    fileWriter.close();

}catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If I use for (int = 0; int <1;) I get the following output which works fine:

```
    Root element :ICD10CM.index
----------------------------
Number of nodes 3

Current Element: letter
Letter: 
      Aarskog's syndrome
      Q87.1

Condition: Aarskog's syndrome
Condition: Abandonment
Condition: Abasia(-astasia) (hysterical)
Condition: Abderhalden-Kaufmann-Lignac syndrome(cystinosis)
Condition: Abdomen, abdominal
Condition: Abdominalgia
Condition: Abduction contracture, hip or other joint
Condition: Azygos
----------------------------
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

However the moment I change to (int = 0; int <2;) I get the following output:

```
    run:
Root element :ICD10CM.index
----------------------------
Number of nodes 3

Current Element: letter
Letter: 
      Aarskog's syndrome
      Q87.1

java.lang.NullPointerException
Condition: Aarskog's syndrome
Condition: Abandonment
Condition: Abasia(-astasia) (hysterical)
Condition: Abderhalden-Kaufmann-Lignac syndrome(cystinosis)
Condition: Abdomen, abdominal
Condition: Abdominalgia
Condition: Abduction contracture, hip or other joint
Condition: Azygos
----------------------------

    at icd10parse.ICD10Parse.main(Current Element: letter
ICD10Parse.java:71)
Letter: 
      Babesiosis
      B60.0

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you debugged that line during the second loop to check which value is null?

Comment: One of your title in `mainTerm` might be missing.

Comment: Did you intentionally leave the end of the XML file?

Comment: @Fxguy1 Under your question there is an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54596739/edit) link so that you can add such information.

Comment: @Fxguy1 Also as further debugging help: Create a file with just two entries and see if the error persists. If so, start removing stuff that you currently skip over. If the problem still persists, post that shortened (Minimal) example.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Ok, updated the original post to use a shortened version of the file. Still getting the same results. Iterates through the letter A fine, but then errors on trying to itterate through the B node.

Answer (score 3):

In general to find a null pointer in a line change all calls in that line into their own line.

So this `condition = tElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(i).getTextContent();` would become this:

```
NodeList elements = tElement.getElementsByTagName("title");
Node item = elements.item(i);
condition = item.getTextContent();
```

That way you will see which of the various parts is causing the Exception and you can narrow down your search. As Colm mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54597182/881272) your mistake most likely is the use of `i` in `.item(i)` in this case. So this answer is aiming more at helping you to figure it out the next time.

Answer (score 2):

Possible cause. You are using the index i to reference a "title" element. But the index i is what you were using to loop through the "letter" elements. If you just want the first title, replace that i with a 1 in the following line:

```
condition = tElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(i).getTextContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I needed another variable for the sub-nodes. It works great now. 
Here is the working code:

```
Node cNode = nList.item(0);
            int v = 0;

            for (int a =0; a<nList.getLength();){

                cNode = nList.item(a);
                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element: " + cNode.getNodeName());
                Element aElement = (Element) cNode;
                System.out.println("Current Letter: " + aElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(v).getTextContent());


                //For each Node, get sub-nodes
                    NodeList lList = aElement.getElementsByTagName("mainTerm");
                     for (int x =0; x<lList.getLength();){
                         Node tNode = lList.item(x);

                        if (cNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                            String condition ="";
                            Element tElement = (Element) tNode;
                            NodeList tList = tElement.getElementsByTagName("title");

                            //Get Condition
                            NodeList elements = tElement.getElementsByTagName("title");
                            Node item = elements.item(v);
                            condition = item.getTextContent();
                            //condition = tElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(i).getTextContent();
                            System.out.println("Condition: " + condition);
                            fileWriter.write(condition +";");     
                        }
                       x++;
                    }
                     a++; 
                }
```

As a side note, instead of using the v variable I could have just set them to 0.